# Need explanation about random function swift

Tags: swift, random

Got a question about my random function: why is it giving this error?

```
'4294967295' is not exactly representable as 'Float'; it becomes '4294967296'
```

-

my code is

```
func random() ->CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func  random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

it doesn't change the functionality of the application but it just appeared out of nowhere.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [IEEE 754 32-bit floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) number has 24 significant bits for the mantissa, that is not enough to store a 10-digit integer exactly:

```
print(0xFFFFFFFF)             // 4294967295
print(Float(0xFFFFFFFF))      // 4.2949673e+09
print(Int(Float(0xFFFFFFFF))) // 4294967296
```

That won't affect your code because

```
Float(arc4random()) / Float(0xFFFFFFFF)
```

is still a floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0. Changing the calculation to

```
return CGFloat(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF
```

will fix the warning on 64-bit platforms: The integer constant is now converted to a (64-bit) `Double`.

But as of Swift 4.2 you can avoid the problem completely by using the new [`Random` API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md):

```
func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.random(in: min...max)
}
```